# Is there a specific ID I should name my Bootstrap Modal to have AdBlock Plus block it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, adblock

Is there a specific ID I should name my Bootstrap Modal to have AdBlock Plus block it?

I want AdBlock Plus to block it if someone has it installed & is using it. I don't want to be overly annoying by working around ABP. Only reason I'm using Modal is because with Bootstrap, it's easy to use.

My HTML is:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="AdModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Email Deals</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Sign up for email-only specials and news updates. We will not sell or rent your email address.</p>
      <p>Sign up now!</p>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="http://www.gliq.com/cgi-bin/subunsub">
        <div class="input-prepend">
        <input type="hidden" name="acctname" value="amleo"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://www.amleo.com/subscribe-successful/a/47/"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your email address" id="inputIcon" class="input-xlarge" name="email">
        <input value="SUBSCRIBE" class="btn btn-orange" type="submit">
        </div>
        </form>
      <p><a href="">Privacy Policy</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ABP by itself doesn't block anything but follows the rules user has installed.

Comment: Look into the rules of the FanBoy's/Easy list for ABP as it is the most likely one to be subscribed to. Find a REGEX that can easily target your ad.

Comment: how would you rent an email address ^^ ?  "now you have to forget and give it back"

Comment: classes/links that contain "ad" or "ads" are normally good

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `banner` as id for your modal. Usually, AdBlock blocks such elements with the highest priority.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a class of `.post_ad` and ABP should block it for most people.

https://adblockplus.org/en/filters

**##.post_ad**

https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt